# Jquery plugin - add class based on nested options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i wish to extend and nest an option with 4 different sub options, which control the position of div thro `css`. I'm stuck on nesting part and my current setup is visible [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m7u61qu6/).

Goal is to be able to set a sub option for window location upon invoke like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#testDiv").testPlugin({
        showDiv: true,
        divLocation: topRight,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how you can to configure it, but I made a little change on your setup; Passing a string into the options and basically just assigning it. Please explain more.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#testDiv").testPlugin({
        showDiv: true,
        divLocation: "topLeft",
    });
});
//And changed this line
$(self).addClass(settings.divLocation);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m7u61qu6/1/